# Game Engine not run action in sensor "always" after sensor "keyboard"

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I´m sorry for my English, I´m Brazilian. I need help, please.

I am creating a game (only to study and learning about BGE), it has two animations `ocioso` and `pulando`.

I can run these animations correctly on BGE, but I wanna continue running the animation with sensor *Always* after the animation with sensor *Keyboard* is finished.

Steps:

1. Press <kbd>P</kbd>, to start game.
2. The cat will look around itself (animation `ocioso`).
3. Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (this call animation `pulando`).
4. When the animation `pulando` finishes, the animation `ocioso` does not
   continue running. Why??

[image: Sensor and actions on BGE]

The download the .blend is at link below:
[image]

Thank´s for all.

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for file uploading instead next time. I don't think you file is publicly accessible. Please edit your question and provided a new link using the site above

Comment: fixed link...thank you...I´m newer in stackexchange...

Comment: Not much into the Game Engine myself, but see if this helps http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-205271.html

Comment: This is a bug in the action actuator (since 2.62 - rework of the animation system). It looks like the override from Action.001 dues not get disabled.